# Entity Framework several One-to-Many with same model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, one-to-many

My `Order` class

```
public class Order
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        (...)

        [ForeignKey("Client")]
        public string ClientID { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Client { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Trader")]
        public string TraderID { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Trader { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Driver")]
        public string DriverID { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Driver { get; set; }
    }
```

And my MS Identity `ApplicationUser` class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        (...)
        public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see I'd like to have speciffic users in speciffic "role" in `Order` model. How should I write a code in `ApplicationUser` to get speciffic lists of Clients, Traders and Drivers? I mean, I'd like to find user in database and then I'd like to have three lists named e.g. `AsClient`, `AsTrader` and `AsDriver`. Right now `List<Orders>` count is always 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `InversePropertyAttribute`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //another stuff...

    [InverseProperty("Client")]
    public virtual ICollection<Order> AsClient { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Trader")]
    public virtual ICollection<Order> AsTrader { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Driver")]
    public virtual ICollection<Order> AsDriver { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a little inheritance here.

So you would create three classes that extend `ApplicationUser`, one for each Trader, Client and Driver. And then on each of these classes have the orders list. Also, on the `Order` class, change the types from `ApplicationUser` to the appropriate subtype.

Then as an inheritance strategy you can choose the **table per hierarchy** and follow the instructions on [this link](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) to implement it.

Hope this helps.